# Not able to run EOSIO module for demux

Tags: nodeos, eosjs

while trying to run demux, I am getting an error.

> The proper initialization has not occurred. Failed to migrate the
>   postgres database.

The full error code is this:

```
{"name":"demux","hostname":"dev-eosio-1","pid":27981,"level":50,"err":{"message":"The proper initialization has not occurred. Failed to migrate the postgres database.","name":"NotInitializedError","stack":"NotInitializedError: The proper initialization has not occurred. Failed to migrate the postgres database.\n at MassiveActionHandler. (/home/nodeos2/demux/node_modules/demux-postgres/dist/MassiveActionHandler.js:103:22)\nTypeError: Invalid query format.\n at Database.$query (/home/nodeos2/demux/node_modules/massive/node_modules/pg-promise/lib/query.js:99:21)\n at Database. (/home/nodeos2/demux/node_modules/massive/node_modules/pg-promise/lib/query.js:259:23)\n at config.$npm.connect.pool.then.db (/home/nodeos2/demux/node_modules/massive/node_modules/pg-promise/lib/database.js:326:42)\n at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"},"msg":"The proper initialization has not occurred. Failed to migrate the postgres database.","time":"2019-09-05T02:45:19.290Z","v":0} 
{"name":"demux","hostname":"dev-eosio-1","pid":27981,"level":30,"msg":"Indexing unexpectedly paused due to an error.","time":"2019-09-05T02:45:19.291Z","v":0}
```

After debugging through the node modules, I got a Promise { }, in Migration.js when calling pgp.none(this.upQueryFile) in the up(pgp) function.

The demux file I am running looks like this,

```
const { BaseActionWatcher } = require("demux")
const { MongoActionReader } = require("demux-eos")
const { MassiveActionHandler } = require("demux-postgres")
const { Migration } = require("demux-postgres")
const massive = require("massive")

// See https://eosio.github.io/demux-js/ for info on Handler Versions, Updaters, and Effects
// const handlerVersions = require("./handlerVersions") // Import your handler versions
const handlerVersions = [
      {
        versionName: 'v1',
        deferUntilIrreversible: true,
      },
  ]

// See "Migrations" section above
//const migrationSequences = require("./migrationSequences")

const createTodoTable = new Migration(
  "table", // name
  "schema", // schema
  "create_todo_table.sql" // SQL file
)

const migrationSequences = [{
  migrations: [createTodoTable],
  sequenceName: "init"
}]

console.log(migrationSequences);

// See https://dmfay.github.io/massive-js/connecting.html for info on massive configuration
const dbConfig = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 5432,
  database: 'postgres',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'pass'
}

massive(dbConfig).then((db) => {
 console.log("logging this",migrationSequences);
    const actionHandler = new MassiveActionHandler(
    handlerVersions,
    db,
    dbConfig.schema,
    migrationSequences
  )
    console.log("logging this",migrationSequences);
  const actionReader = new MongoActionReader({
    startAtBlock: 1234,              // startAtBlock: the first block relevant to our application
    onlyIrreversible: false,         // onlyIrreversible: whether or not to only process irreversible blocks
    dbName: "EOS2",                   // name of the database
    mongoEndpoint: "mongodb://user:pass@127.0.0.1:27017/EOS2",    // mongoEndpoint: the url of the mongodb instance
  })
  const actionWatcher = new BaseActionWatcher(actionReader, actionHandler, 500)
  actionReader.initialize().then(()=>
  actionWatcher.watch())
})
//async function migrateDatabase(db, payload) {
//  await db.migrate(payload.sequenceName)}
```

What is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by using different version of `pg-promise`. `QueryFile` class from different version of `pg-promise` are incompatible. ([vitaly-t/pg-promise#393](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues/393))

`demux-postgres` depends on `massive@5.7.2` and `pg-promise@8.5.3`, but `demux-eos` depends on `massive@^5.7.5`, so installed `massive` on root of node_modules and `massive` on which `demux-postgres` depends will be different:

```
├┬massive@5.7.7
│└─pg-promise@8.5.6
├┬demux-postgres@4.0.1
│└┬massive@5.7.2
│ └─pg-promise@8.5.3
```

Refer to https://github.com/EOSIO/demux-js-postgres/issues/67.